# Select a column from a dataframe and return as a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and would like to extract 1 column, retaining the column heading and keeping the dataframe structure.  The following is an example using the in-built mtcars data

```
df = mtcars

va = df$wt
va = as.data.frame(va)
names(va)<-c("wt")
```

Is there are more efficient way of doing this?  Or a way to automate the transfer of the column name (in this case I know the name, but may not always).

In practice I am using the subset command to identify rows that meet certain criteria, and then extracting the one column that has information that varies (in case this presents another approach).  It needs to be a dataframe for some other packages to work correctly.

Comment: just use `mtcars[, "wt", drop = FALSE]` or `mtcars[ 'wt']`.

Comment: Thanks - that solves the problem.  I had used drop in association with subset, but couldn't get that working in this context (forgot about the [] notation option)